# How to write f[ t[i],...,t[i+r] ]=f [t[i+1],...,t[i+r] ]- f[ t[i] ,...,t[i+r-1] ] in Mathematica for 0 <= i <= n , 0<= r <= n

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm, sequence, differentials

[image]

For[[[[[[[[[[[Do[]]]]]]]]]]]]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the question in the title:

```
n = 8;
r = 6;
i = 3;

Array[t, r, i, f] == Array[t, r - 1, i + 1, f] - Array[t, r - 1, i, f]

(*    f[t[3], t[4], t[5], t[6], t[7], t[8]] ==
      f[t[4], t[5], t[6], t[7], t[8]] - f[t[3], t[4], t[5], t[6], t[7]]    *)
```

For your code, better use `t[i]` instead of $t_i$ subscripts.